# Android Studio - Select multiple pictures from (normal) gallery

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want a user to be able to select multiple images from the 'normal' gallery. It currently opens a sort of file explorer instead of the gallery. Is there anything I can do so it uses the 'normal' gallery?

I currently open the file explorer/gallery the following way:

```
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    gallery.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Select Picture"), 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter the results for image type. Something like this:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

Adding this would probably be enough for your code:

```
gallery.setType("image/*");
```

Comment: `ACTION_PICK` does not use the MIME type and is not documented to support `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want a user to be able to select multiple images from the 'normal' gallery

There are over 20,000 Android device models. There will be dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed gallery apps, in addition to those that users install. There is no "normal".

There is also no requirement for any of those gallery apps to support multiple selection.

> It currently opens a sort of file explorer instead of the gallery.

My guess is that you are referring to the UI brought up by `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

> Is there anything I can do so it uses the 'normal' gallery?

Remove the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` line, so that your `Intent` action is `ACTION_PICK`.

Bear in mind that since `ACTION_PICK` is not documented to support `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` — and since support for extras is always optional — very few devices are likely to return multiple images to you.

Also bear in mind that `ACTION_PICK` is not guaranteed to display something that you might consider to be a gallery app.